# How can I listen to FM Radio streaming without connecting to the internet?

Tags: audio, streaming, radio

Many phones has the functionality to listen to FM radio without connecting to the internet. Just wondering that how can I do this on a computer? Please give me some advices, thanks a lot.

For a computer I mean a notebook which already has the wireless and Bluetooth, and these two combination shall be able for a notebook to perform this functionality.

Comment: This just proves that what is old becomes new again.  :-)

Comment: Just get a FM radio with audio out and connect it to your computer's audio in.

Comment: I have a simple USB device which you plug into your PC, plug a headphone into the device and thats it. Basically it only draws power from the USB port. (No, I never use it, I received one for free but I don't really like FM radio. Same reason like TV. Can't bear listening/watching ads always.)

Answer (score 3):

You will need an FM receiver for your computer.

Comment: Is FM receiver a wireless? How can I use it? Please be more specify. Thanks you for answering.

Comment: An FM receiver is essentially a radio. Your granny will be able to tell you more about this revolutionary technology, or you can consult Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio

Comment: There may be an FM radio somewhere that will send its audio to your computer via Bluetooth, but most computers have pretty poor loudspeakers -- you'd be better off just listening to the radio.  But you can usually find a cable to connect the two.
There have been a few FM tuner cards for desktop computers, but since you're using a notebook - no.

Comment: this won't pick up streaming tho.  of course, the way the question is written, the correct answer is "you can't."  also, leave the "not exactly programming related" comments *in the comments* -- so that your answers don't contain them when they get migrated.

Answer (score -1):

Look for (on sites that sell older hardware) a device called a RadioShark.  It is a USB radio tuner that shows up as an audio card in the computer.  Although it's software was written for older Windows and Mac machines, I've managed to create a Docker container that runs some Linux code to manage the tuner (search Github for the software).